# Securely store data on a web server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

I'm planning on making an android application that sends user data to a web server and stores it temporarily in a database. Now I've never worked with databases or web servers before, but after reading a bunch of tutorials and a few days of hacking away I managed to get a node.js server with mongodb up and running on the openshift platform.

Right now anyone can interact with the database just by sending a GET request or even just pulling up the url in a browser. Is there a way to prevent that by happening or would I have to maybe encrypt the data myself before storing it?

Comment: What is the purpose of your application? Is each piece of data specific to some user who owns it? If it's a problem that anyone can see any data, it sounds like you need to have authenticated requests (e.g., make the user log in with a username and password), and the server must verify the credentials before any data will be returned.

Comment: @apsillers One of the functions of the app will let users see how many other people are using the app in the area, so I planned to have each device send its location to the server and have the server send back a list of users who are nearby.

Comment: @Waves, if you choose to use HTML5 geolocation APIs, future versions of Chrome will require the use of HTTPS

Comment: @Waves Note that it's very easy to spoof a computer's physical location, so even if you locked down your server as hard as you could, the user could trivially make their machine pretend to be in another place, and your server would have no way of knowing that client is lying. To put it another way: the user's physical location is never a secure mechanism to control access to data, because a client can trivially lie about its location.

Comment: @JaredDykstra Since the app will be on the android platform, would I still need to use HTTPS ?

Comment: @apsillers It's not so much that I'm worried about fake locations being stored as much as I'm worried about someone with malicious intent pinging the server for people's locations...

Comment: @Waves Right, so your HTTP listener should only accept a location parameter. Make it so that users can send an HTTP request to ask the server, "Which users are currently near point `(lat, long)`?" and can provide any lat/long they please. The client can the default point be the user's current location. If you don't want to allow queries for a specific user's location, then *don't* write an HTTP listener that allows users to ask the question, "What is the location of user `foo`?" Of course, the first query allows a user to check some specific place(s) for specific users. This is unavoidable.

Comment: @apsillers Ah okay, so I was just driving myself into a corner with the way I set up the listeners then. I'm gonna go with your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe a typical web application using REST APIs.  To secure it, do two things:

1. Deploy your REST APIs (or the entire site) using HTTPS instead of HTTP.  This provides end to end encryption so your sensitive data cannot be viewed while in transit
2. Add an authentication and authorization mechanism, so that only authenticated endpoints can access your REST APIs.

Comment: As you're using Node.js, you may want to consider http://passportjs.org for authentication.